Why does GCC fail to find gtk/gtk.h when compiling a GTK4 program on Arch Linux?
I'm trying to run the "Hello World" example from the official GTK documentation:
GTK Hello World Example
I followed the instructions and ran the following command:
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)

However, I got this error:
hello-world-gtk.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

I have GTK4 installed, and the directory /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk exists, so the file gtk.h is present. It seems like GCC can't find the library despite using pkg-config.
Additional Information:

System: Arch Linux, kernel version 6.11.9-arch1-1

Installed GTK version: gtk4 (confirmed via pacman -Q gtk4)

pkg-config seems to work when I test it:
pkg-config --cflags gtk4

Outputs something like:
-I/usr/include/gtk-4.0

Similarly, pkg-config --libs gtk4 outputs the correct linker flags.


Despite all this, GCC still can't find the header.

Verified the gtk.h file exists in /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk.
Reinstalled gtk4 and pkg-config via pacman.
Checked that pkg-config outputs the correct flags (as shown above).

What might I be missing, and how can I fix this issue?
(btw. clangd has the same issue and prints tons of errors because it cant find the library)

Here some additional log based on the comments:

gtk.h exists and is accessible:
The file /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h is present and readable:
.rw-r--r-- 11k root  1 Nov 20:21 /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h


Expanded compilation command:
The full command generated by pkg-config is:
gcc -I/usr/include/gtk-4.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/lib/graphene-1.0/include -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/sysprof-6 -pthread -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c -lgtk-4 -lharfbuzz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lvulkan -lgraphene-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0


Direct -I flag:
Attempting to compile with -I/usr/include/gtk-4.0 results in:
fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory


Output of pkg-config:
pkg-config --cflags gtk4 correctly includes:
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include


Environment variable check:
PKG_CONFIG_PATH is empty, so there should be no interference:
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
(no output)


Output of gcc -v


Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,d,fortran,go,lto,m2,objc,obj-c++,rust --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/gcc/-/issues --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.1 20240910 (GCC)


Output of pacman -Qi gcc

Name            : gcc
Version         : 14.2.1+r134+gab884fffe3fc-1
Description     : The GNU Compiler Collection - C and C++ frontends
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://gcc.gnu.org
Licenses        : GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception  GFDL-1.3-or-later
Groups          : None
Provides        : gcc-multilib
Depends On      : gcc-libs=14.2.1+r134+gab884fffe3fc-1  binutils>=2.28  libmpc
                  zstd  libisl.so=23-64
Optional Deps   : lib32-gcc-libs: for generating code for 32-bit ABI
Required By     : base-devel  clang  dmd  rust  vala
Optional For    : dmd  node-gyp  xorg-xrdb
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : gcc-multilib
Installed Size  : 202,47 MiB
Packager        : Frederik Schwan <freswa@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : 2024-09-10T15:07:33 CEST
Install Date    : 2024-11-09T22:09:28 CET
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature


You say "so the file gtk.h is present", but you cannot conclude by the presence of a directory that the specific file wanted is present.  Is it?  Path exactly equal to /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h?  And is that file readable by you?

Can't reproduce on Arch x86_64 with gtk4 1:4.16.5-1 and gcc 14.2.1+r134+gab884fffe3fc-1: no errors with #include <gtk/gtk.h>. Can you show full expanded command you use for compilation? (E.g. type it in shell prompt but don't press Enter. Press Esc, then Ctrl+E).

What happens if you try to use -I/usr/include/gtk-4.0 directly instead of $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4)? Also, "something like" isn't really a precisy statement.

I updated my question with additional information, it still doesn't work but maybe the additional log helps you to understand the issue

Please add also gcc -v and pacman -Qi gccoutput.

added gcc -v and pacman -Qi gcc

It looks like $(...) is not substituted with flags during command execution by shell. What shell do you use? What terminal emulator? Try to run full expanded command from (2). Try to run compilation command under /bin/bash --login --norc --noprofile

$(pkg-config ...) might be substituted to empty string when mistakenly used in Makefile. You type the command in shell prompt, not in Makefile, don't you?

You were right—the issue was that I was using the fish shell. Switching to bash or running the command with /bin/bash -c "gcc \$(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c \$(pkg-config --libs gtk4)" works fine.
However, I’m still encountering an issue where clangd doesn’t recognize the library and shows a lot of errors. Is there a way to configure clangd to avoid this?

Apparently, I need to create a .clangd file and explicitly add the libraries. What I don’t understand is why clangd can’t find these libraries, even though they are located under /usr/include/....

alright, solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78044813/clangd-with-gtk-on-lunarvim-emitting-too-many-errors-compiling-and-executing-al
thanks for your help!
